# Creating an eye/eyelid rig for dragon without shape keys

Tags: rigging

I've been creating a dragon lately and now trying to create a rig for my dragon. I've managed to create a basic rig for other body parts of my dragon, but I' m really stuck at creating eye and eyelid rigs as I can't find tutorials of creating them for dragon.

This is how my eye looks like. I've created it by using lattice to stretch it (so it would look like a real dragon eye). The eyelids are separated from the eye itself.

**Dragon eye with lattice and eyelids as seperate objects**
[image: Dragon eye]

When I move the eyelid in front view using 3D cursor as pivot point, it moves nicely around the eye, but I can' t understand how to make this work with bones.

**Eyelid open**

[image]

**Eyelid closed**

[image]

The second problem - I can' t make a basic eyerig for this kind of eye, because it is not round and stretched by lattice. Whenever I try to move the eye somewhere using the eyebone in pose mode, it'll look like this. How could I overcome this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning the eye movement, you can use a UVWarp modifier to your eye.

[image]

The principle is to set two objects (empties) to shift the position of the UV map of the eye.
Moving (or inserting key frames) one empty will shift the UV map to obtain the result.

Here is a closer view of the modifier :
[image]

Edit :
Concerning the eyelid animation, if you set the bone origine at the same position your 3D cursor is (as you said you can rotate it manually), that may work.

[image]

Another edit : a rigged version of the eye animation.

The principle is simply to add a "Bone" and define a group named "Bone" for the Iris circle. That allow to play on the position and X-scale of the iris.

[image]

The Bone group is the iris / center UVs in the image below :
[image]

Comment: Oh. That's a cool solution. I will truly try this out, but what I actually prefer is mesh. I think it would be easier to animate it later on when I need the dragon to look at certain places.

Comment: I managed to create some kind of eyerig for my character, which partly solves the problem, but now there' s a problem with the Limit Rotation constraint. It's moving so weird. 

When I look the bone rotation it's all zeros. When I try to use zero degrees as min value, my eye pupil will move to somewhere else.
https://gyazo.com/20346fae0cf07d28d6a0ac564497790d

Comment: edited for a rigged version of the iris movement.