# Can bones influence textures?

Tags: texturing, armature, bones

I have a character with non-spherical eyes. Is there another way to move the pupils without resorting to re-positioning the UV map permanently? Like say... assigning the texture to a bone?

Comment: You could use drivers to control a mapping node in your materials setup to warp how the UVs are applied. I am not familiar enough with the process to make a good description of this though. Another alternative you could try is making the pupil a separate piece of geometry and controlling that with a bone, and using shrinkwrap to make it conform to the eye surface.

Comment: have a look here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55295/creating-an-eye-eyelid-rig-for-dragon-without-shape-keys/55296#55296

Comment: Both of Sazerac's methods seem pretty taxing, but I really like the first suggestion. I can't seem to find any videos or threads explaining this in detail. The UV warp suggestion isn't too bad either, but since my model has multiple textures how would I specify which UV arrangement to warp?

Answer (score -3):

you can assign a texture to a mesh, them assign that mesh to a bone.

Comment: This answer doesn't really describe any useful details about how to achieve this.

Comment: perhaps you can do a better job

Comment: I posed the question to ascertain how to achieve that very action.