# How can I move a UV Island to simulate the Movement of an Eye

Tags: uv

SO I have a Plane instead of a Sphere for the Eye, I want to be able to move the UV Island instead of moving parts of the plane or using a Sphere.

The eyes are Oval Shaped so I have to use a plane for the eyes. So I would like to be able to Slide, Scale, and Rotate the UV Island (Not move any of the Geometry) instead of the traditional methods. I know AnimAll is a choice but AnimAll causes the Program to Freeze then Crash for me. So is there a way I can move the UV Island using a Bone that I move around kinda like in this image below.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move a UV Island using a Bone](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60552/how-do-i-move-a-uv-island-using-a-bone)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60552/how-do-i-move-a-uv-island-using-a-bone?rq=1, It would be preferrable to update the original with any clarifications rather than creating a new question.

Comment: I just removed the Old one because no one would have seen it anyways, the guy on that one didn't even show me exactly what I wanted.

Comment: One of the comments on the old one actually linked to similar question with an answer that would have solved your problem. See writup of the UVWarp modifier in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55295/creating-an-eye-eyelid-rig-for-dragon-without-shape-keys, also https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_warp.html

Comment: I'm doing all this on a single Texture Image, I'm not the best at blender even, but there isn't really much of an Explanation for me to understand on that answer he gave.

Comment: And even when I do figure out how to use the modifier I can't set the center, and I can't scale things without the whole Texture Stretching.

Comment: In this case you may find it easier to unwrap the eyes into a second UV map and use a separate image. I'm not super familiar with the UV Warp modifier so I'll leave it to someone else to provide a proper answer. That said, the UV Warp modifier is how I have always seen this effect achieved.

Comment: It would have been more constructive to indicate the problems you met rather than delete and repost the same question... About this new answer, if that still don't work for you, definitely you should use another texture (and eventually another UV map)

Comment: I wonder if it's necessary to have two eyes drawn inside the texture for both eyes of the 3D model? If they share the same texture, wouldn't it be more efficient to make UV islands overlap and use the same space of the UV with a single sprite drawn for them?

Answer (score 5):

Ok... it seems it is needed to complete a previous answer ([Creating an eye/eyelid rig for dragon without shape keys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55295/creating-an-eye-eyelid-rig-for-dragon-without-shape-keys))...

You are more or less in this situation with a single UV map and a single texture. The eyes are here selected on the left.

On the right, you can see two vertex groups (named WarpLeftEye and WarpRightEye) : each of them is assigned the corresponding eye vertices.

[image]

Now, add two empties. Here I created a sphere and a cube one (in order to see who is who). Then setup the UV Warp modifier this way, using the two empties (or any objects or bones) and the vertex group for the left eye (do the same for the other eye) :

[image]

Here is the result :

[image]

Surely, you'll need to have enough space around the eyes in your texture. If not, add another one as suggested in the comments.
You can also use the UV map field of the modifier to use another UV map done for the eyes.

Note : scaling and rotating work too... more or less easy to do but simply scale and move and/or rotate the empty (scaling will shift too : so you'll need to scale a bit, realign, scale a bit, etc.)

Comment: And my Apologies for the first time.

Comment: @JamesAppleMan, thanks (that was not needed though). It is more for the principle of the site than for me.