# How do you make low poly textured eyes blink

Tags: texturing, topology

I am confused on how that works do I just scale the plane that holds that portion of the eyes down or is there a way to animate that portion of the texture without copying a 2d artist.

Comment: A way to do it is to use the 'UV warp modifier'. The principle here : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61660/how-can-i-move-a-uv-island-to-simulate-the-movement-of-an-eye/61673#61673. And a more complete tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BopkonvbCEE