# Are there any methods to make rigs using just texture eyes on spheres or flat surfaces obj?

Tags: texturing, uv, rigging

I'm a beginner. I want to know how to rig the texture eye on the flat plane I made. Here is the picture below. How do I set the rig on it, so it follows it? I would appreciate an explanation of pictures or gifs so that I could better understand them.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move a UV Island to simulate the Movement of an Eye](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61660/how-can-i-move-a-uv-island-to-simulate-the-movement-of-an-eye)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Pons de Leon's answer, there's also the *UV Project* modifier, give it to your object and choose an empty as controller:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add an empty to the scene, select your plane, on the shader editor select your eye node, hit ***ctrl + T*** to get access to it's coordinate (to get access to this feature enable node wrangler add-on) or manually add the mapping and texture coordinate nodes. select your empty with the eyedropper (bottom of the texture coordinate node) to use it's coordinate as the texture coordinate

[image]

your  texture will follow the movement of the empty