# How Can You Animate a Flat Eye Texture?

Tags: animation, objects

So, I have a VRM that I've exported into a GLB file as of now. Issue is, the eyes iris or pupil isn't movable because of it's pupil being flat, and it's a texture. I've looked up ways to fix this like AnimAll but I don't get it, and it's not really helping.
Anyone know how to fix this?

--
The thing is, I'm new to the software so I don't know where it is.
[image]
I'm in UV Editor, But I have no idea where the UV Warp is, I'm very new to it.

Comment: Perhaps a picture in your question will make it clearer.

Comment: Possibiliies (by others): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55295/creating-an-eye-eyelid-rig-for-dragon-without-shape-keys/55296#55296 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61660/how-can-i-move-a-uv-island-to-simulate-the-movement-of-an-eye/61673#61673

Answer (score 1):

If its a texture and you want to animate that check UV Wrap modifier in the modifier tab of the object.

[image]

Then, you can animate the texture in the Transform options of the UV Wrap modifier.

[image]