# Where is the UV Warp? Is it in UV Editing Tab?

Tags: animation, objects

I've heard of "UV Warp", that can allow me to edit and animate a Texture the Eyes of my model.

But I have no idea where it is in UV Editing, or how to get it.

[image]

This is my setup, and this is how it is in UV Editing.

Comment: : ( ... this is in the modifiers tab. This time, I won't indicate to close this """new""" question, but please this site is not to teach all from a to z. Read the documation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_warp.html

Comment: Again this should meet your need https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55295/creating-an-eye-eyelid-rig-for-dragon-without-shape-keys/55296#55296