# Oval eye rig for game engine

Tags: rigging, game-engine, unity

For a character that has really big eyes, it isnt possible to use the standard spherical eyes. I need to make the eyes oval. But then the problem comes with the rigging. Would it be possible that the oval eyes can be rigged in such a way that they can be used in unity?

Comment: Does Unity support the shrinkwrap modifier?

Comment: does Unity support Lattice modifier? An alternative would be to move the texture like I explain in the following link but again I guess it depends on Unity: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206867/how-do-i-fit-those-eyes-into-my-character-mesh/206878#206878

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55295/creating-an-eye-eyelid-rig-for-dragon-without-shape-keys/55296#55296 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61660/how-can-i-move-a-uv-island-to-simulate-the-movement-of-an-eye/61673#61673

Comment: The shrinkwrap modifier would be applied as in blender. So it wont be of use.

Comment: I dont know if textures will behave the same way in unity. I am not a unity user. I am working on a character for someone else. If the behave the same way then that would be great