# How to make a 2D eye attach with 3D model's face, then add a rig to the eyes so they are able to move around the face?

Tags: modeling, mesh, grease-pencil, blend-files, 2d

I'm trying to make 2D eyes on my model character's face. How do I stick on face and how to rig eyes on face. You know, moving up and down and side and move anywhere around on the face. Please answer if you know the question.

Comment: hello, could you please show some screenshots? it would help

Answer (score 0):

Typically the way to use 2D-Images in 3D is UV-Mapping. This technique maps specific parts of the image to specific faces of the model. Then you work with the model and do things like rigging and movements. For example you can model the basic shape of an eye with spheres, unwrap the sphere onto an 2d plane (the image) and rig the sphere.

You may want to look for some tutorials about UV-Mapping like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBUfMKKZDo

Comment: I'm missing an important keyword here: ***UV Warp Modifier***. With this modifier, you can change the texture mapping for 2D face expressions. Examples: https://youtu.be/beTOy-dwOOc and https://youtu.be/BopkonvbCEE or here at BSE: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/55295/107598

Comment: nice! never done things like this